# Loop thru List of IDs

Tags: sql, sql-server

I am trying to figure out how to change my query to accept multiple values for the @agentid instead of just one and then loop through the query for each agentid. I guess I am hung-up on how to declare that and then which loop to use. Any help would be greatly appreciated!

```
declare
@Startdate datetime,
@Enddate datetime,
@agentid varchar(100)

set @startdate = '4/17/2023'
set @enddate = '8/07/2023'
set @agentid = '1024971' --would like to change to ('12345','6789','98763','246810') as example and then loop through code below for each id in the list.

--AS
--BEGIN
SET NOCOUNT ON

/* 
DECLARE @YearStart AS datetime =  '2019-11-20 00:00:00', @Startdate AS datetime = '2019-11-17 00:00:00', @Enddate AS datetime =  '2019-11-25 00:00:00'
   */
DELETE FROM tblGenesys
FROM            tblGenesys INNER JOIN
                         tblUsers2 AS u ON tblGenesys.AgentID = u.GenesysLogon AND tblGenesys.AgentSummaryDate = u.ExtractDate
WHERE ([AgentSummaryDate] >= @Startdate and [AgentSummaryDate] < DATEADD(dd,1,@Enddate)) AND [GenesysGroupName] = 'US' and u.employeeid = @agentid

INSERT INTO [dbo].[tblGenesys]
( 
[Username], [AgentSummaryDate], [GenesysGroupName], [AgentNameRaw], [AgentIDRaw], [LastName], [FirstName], [AgentID],
AgentIDSuffix, [Account], [AccountGroup], [AccountOrganization], [Supervisor], [SVP], [JobTitle], [Client_Paid],
 [TotalDuration], [InboundCount], [InboundTime], [OutboundCount], [OutboundTime], [InternalCount], [InternalTime],
  [HoldTime], [ACWTime], [WaitTime], [DialTime], [BreakTime], FaxEmailTime, [LeadTime], [LunchTime], [Meet_TrainTime],
   [OtherTime], [ProjectTime], [SystemIssueTime], [NotReadyTime], [HRTime], [ManualWorkTime], [OtherChannelTime], [Transferred], 
   [WeekOf], [DayOfWeek], [MonthOf], GenesysLogon
)
SELECT 
g.[Username], [AgentSummaryDate], [GroupName], [AgentNameRaw], [AgentIDRaw], g.[LastName], g.[FirstName], [AgentID],
AgentIDSuffix, g.[Account], g.[AccountGroup], g.[AccountOrganization], g.[Supervisor], g.[SVP], g.[JobTitle], [Client_Paid],
 [TotalDuration], [InboundCount], [InboundTime], [OutboundCount], [OutboundTime], [InternalCount], [InternalTime],
  [HoldTime], [ACWTime], [WaitTime], [DialTime], [BreakTime], FaxEmailTime, [LeadTime], [LunchTime], [Meet_TrainTime],
   [OtherTime], [ProjectTime], [SystemIssueTime], [NotReadyTime], [HRTime], [ManualWorkTime], [OtherChannelTime], [TranMake], 
   DATEADD(DD, 2 - DATEPART(DW, DATEADD(DD, 0, agentsummarydate)), DATEADD(DD, 0, agentsummarydate)) as WeekOf, LEFT(DATENAME(dw, CAST(agentsummarydate AS DATE)), 3) 
                      AS DayOfWeek, LEFT(DATENAME(mm, CAST(agentsummarydate AS DATE)), 3) + '-' + RIGHT(DATENAME(YY, CAST(agentsummarydate AS DATE)), 2)  AS [MonthOf], g.AgentID
FROM [uv_Genesys_AgentSummaryGroup_CST] as g inner join
tblusers2 as u on g.AgentID = u.GenesysLogon and g.AgentSummaryDate = u.ExtractDate
where [AgentSummaryDate] >= @Startdate and [AgentSummaryDate] < DATEADD(dd,1,@Enddate) and u.EmployeeID = @agentid
ORDER BY [AgentSummaryDate], [LastName] , [FirstName]


-- Select for presentation in report
SELECT count(*) as [RecordsInsertedTable], min(D.[AgentSummaryDate]) as [FirstDate] ,min(D.[WeekOf]) as [FirstWeekOf],max(D.[AgentSummaryDate]) as [LastDate]
,max(D.[WeekOf]) as [LastWeekOf],min(D.[CreateDate]) as [FirstDBCreateDate],max(D.[CreateDate]) as [LastDBCreateDate]
FROM [dbo].[tblGenesys] as D with(nolock) inner join
tblUsers2 as u on D.AgentID = u.GenesysLogon and D.AgentSummaryDate = u.ExtractDate
WHERE D.[AgentSummaryDate] >= @Startdate And  D.[AgentSummaryDate] < DATEADD(dd,1,@Enddate) AND D.[GenesysGroupName] = 'US' and u.EmployeeID = @agentid
```

Comment: You can use multiple option like table variable. Or you can use split string. But you have to change query syntax little bit.

Comment: You don't loop in SQL (normally), because its a set based language. So you need to learn to think in sets of data and carry out operations on sets.

Comment: Please provide a [mre] with sample data and desired results.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Turn `@agentid` into a temp table.

```
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS #AgentID

SELECT
    A.AgentID
INTO #AgentID
FROM
    (
    VALUES
         ('1234')
        ,('2341')
        ,('3412')
        ,('4123')
    ) A(AgentID)
```

Then, do an Inner Join at any table that has an `AgentID` field to join to and limit your query pull.

```
FROM [uv_Genesys_AgentSummaryGroup_CST] AS G 
INNER JOIN tblusers2 AS U
    ON  G.AgentID = U.GenesysLogon 
    AND G.AgentSummaryDate = U.ExtractDate
INNER JOIN #AgentID AS AI 
    ON  G.AgentID = AI.AgentID
```

Lastly, remove any `AND U.AgentID = @agentid` from all of your where statements.

The format requires the following:

- From statement will have an open & close parentheses. `From (...)`
- Table must be named, and have the column name identified inside parenthesis. `From (...) AS A(ColName)`
- Inside the From parenthesis, you will use `VALUES (val1),(val2),...(valn)`

To make formatting easier, list your ID's in Excel using column A. Then run the formula `=CONCAT("('", TEXTJOIN("'),('", TRUE(), A:A), "')")`. This will format your agent ids into the required syntax for this method.

Limitations:
You will be limited to approximately 1000 ids or less. So only useful for small to medium scale needs.

Comment: This approach makes sense, but I do have a question.  Will the code then read in all of the values in the temp table at once or how does that work? Thanks!

Comment: I don't know the exact technical process of this, but that is essentially how I understand it to work.

Comment: This is the approach I use all the time when my queries potentially require more than 1 entry for lookup.

Answer (score 0):

something like this

```
 CREATE FUNCTION [dbo].[fn_Split_String]
(
   @List NVARCHAR(MAX),
   @Delimiter NVARCHAR(255)
)
RETURNS TABLE
WITH SCHEMABINDING AS
RETURN
  WITH E1(N)        AS ( SELECT 1 UNION ALL SELECT 1 UNION ALL SELECT 1 UNION ALL SELECT 1 
                         UNION ALL SELECT 1 UNION ALL SELECT 1 UNION ALL SELECT 1 
                         UNION ALL SELECT 1 UNION ALL SELECT 1 UNION ALL SELECT 1),
       E2(N)        AS (SELECT 1 FROM E1 a, E1 b),
       E4(N)        AS (SELECT 1 FROM E2 a, E2 b),
       E42(N)       AS (SELECT 1 FROM E4 a, E2 b),
       cteTally(N)  AS (SELECT 0 UNION ALL SELECT TOP (DATALENGTH(ISNULL(@List,1))) 
                         ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY (SELECT NULL)) FROM E42),
       cteStart(N1) AS (SELECT t.N+1 FROM cteTally t
                         WHERE (SUBSTRING(@List,t.N,1) = @Delimiter OR t.N = 0))
  SELECT Item = SUBSTRING(@List, s.N1, ISNULL(NULLIF(CHARINDEX(@Delimiter,@List,s.N1),0)-s.N1,8000))
    FROM cteStart s;
 

declare
@Startdate datetime,
@Enddate datetime,
@agentid varchar(100)  ='xx,yy,ff,dd',  
@x  varchar(50) = 1
declare @agentid_list table (id varchar(50) , RN varchar(50))

insert into @agentid_list
SELECT *  ,ROW_NUMBER()over(order by (select 1) )  RN
from [dbo].[fn_Split_String](@agentid,',')



WHILE (SELECT max(RN) FROM @agentid_list) >= @x
BEGIN

    SELECT * FROM @agentid_list where rn = @x 
    --u.EmployeeID = (SELECT id FROM @agentid_list  where rn = @x)

    set @x = @x +1
END
```

Comment: Wny not use the native (as of sql server 2016) STRING_SPLIT? https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/string-split-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver16

Comment: STRING_SPLIT requires the user be on SQL Server 2016 or better AND the database cannot have compatibility turned on. In my experience, people are still running their databases with compatibility turned on to continue working with older applications.